# How can I successfully combine the logic of these two JUnit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am writing some unit tests for a relatively simple class:

```
public class Asylum {
    List<Guard> guards = new ArrayList<Guard>();
    List<Inmate> inmates = new ArrayList<Inmate>();

    public void addGuard(Guard g) { //... }
    public void addInmate(Inmate i) { //... }
}
```

My unit tests for these two functions determine what happens if I pass in a null value:

```
@Test
public void addGuardNullValue() {
    asylum.addGuard(null);
    assertEquals(0, asylum.getNumGuards());
}

@Test
public void addInmateNullValue() {
    asylum.addInmate(null);
    assertEquals(0, asylum.getNumInmates());
}
```

I actually have a few (> 3) of these containers of guards, inmates, wardens, etc. but I would rather not write what is basically the same unit test for all of their classes.

Is there any way I can boil this down to one unit test to cover *n* classes?

(Please note, I am unable to create an overarching parent class for Guard and Inmate, and I am unable to create an Interface that they both can implement.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see only two solutions, and I wouldn't recommend either.

The first is to use reflection. List all methods in the class and select those with names like `add*` or `getNum*`. Then you could call the `add*` one with a null value and check the return value of `getNum*`. The problem is that you can have false positives in the method names (`addGroup`) and the resulting test would be hard to read (and write).

The second solution would be a method `addPerson(PersonType type, Object person)` which downcasts `person` depending on `PersonType`. I find this a terrible option because it removes the static type check, adds unnecessary complexity and is prone to further abuse. I mention because you may find some useful variation.

My final answer is "don't do it, it's not worth it". You'll need more lines, but they are extremely easy to read and write and will probably be bug-free at the first try.

I would like to end with a quote I find fitting:

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug it. (Brian Kernighan)

Answer (score 1):

First. The right answer IMO is the one from BoppreH. Don't do it.

But here is how you can do it using Reflection.
You might as well start reading the documentation on [The Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

```
package sandbox;
......
......
@Test
public void testAddClasses() throws Exception {
    String classesToTest[] = new String[]{"Inmate", "Guard"};
    for (String classToTest : classesToTest){
        String fullClassName = "sandbox." + classToTest;
        String addMethodName = "add" + classToTest;
        String countMethodName = "getNum" + classToTest + "s"; 

        Asylum asylum = new Asylum();

        Class asylumClass = asylum.getClass();
        Class testClass = Class.forName(fullClassName, true, asylumClass.getClassLoader());

        Method addMethod = asylumClass.getDeclaredMethod(addMethodName, testClass);
        Object voidObj = addMethod.invoke(asylum, (Object)null);

        Method countMethod = asylumClass.getDeclaredMethod(countMethodName, null);
        int count = (int) countMethod.invoke(asylum, null);

        assertEquals(0, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative!